# SQL Server : Join on several tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I need to do a query with the following criteria. I have `table1`, `table2` and `table3`. I need to check that each of `table2` and `table3` are subsets of `table1`.

All of the content of `table1` should be present in `table2` and/or `table3`. All the content of `table1` could be present in `table2` alone and sometimes all the content of `table1` should be present in `table3` only. Other times `table1` could be the content of `table2` and `table3`. Not everything in `table2` should match what is in `table3`.

I want the query to return what is present in `table1` and not find in `table2` nor in `table3`. In addition, it should return what is present in `table2` and `table3` and not present in `table1`.

I have tried the below but it doesnt seem working. Do you have any idea how this could be solved?

```
Select 
    dr1.col1, dr1.col2 
from 
    table1 dr1 
left outer join 
    (Select c.col1, col2 from table2) dr2 on dr1.col1 = dr2.col1 
                                          and dr1.col2 = dr2.col2 
left outer join 
    (Select col1, col2, col3 from tabl3 ) dr3 on dr1.col1 = dr3.col1 
                                              and dr1.col2 = dr3.col2 
                                              and dr1.col3 = dr3.col3 
where 
    dr1.col1 is NULL or dr2.col2 is NULL
```

Comment: That where clause doesn't quite look right, checking dr1 and dr2 - instead of d2 and dr3 - and if its in dr1 but not in either of dr2 or dr3 - you would be checking dr2 AND dr3, not OR.

Answer (score 1):

Use `FULL JOIN` with `UNION`:

```
DECLARE @t1 TABLE ( ID INT )
DECLARE @t2 TABLE ( ID INT )
DECLARE @t3 TABLE ( ID INT )


INSERT  INTO @t1
VALUES  ( 1 ),( 2 ),( 3 ),( 4 ),( 5 ),( 6 ),( 7 ),( 8 ),( 9 )

INSERT  INTO @t2
VALUES  ( 1 ),( 2 ),( 3 ),( 4 )

INSERT  INTO @t3
VALUES  ( 4 ),( 5 ),( 6 ),( 7 ),( 8 ),( 10 )


SELECT  ISNULL(t.ID, tt.ID) AS ID ,
        CASE WHEN t.ID IS NULL THEN 'Missing in Table 1'
             ELSE 'Missing in Table 2, 3'
        END AS MissingValue
FROM    @t1 t
        FULL JOIN ( SELECT  ID FROM    @t2
                    UNION
                    SELECT  ID FROM    @t3
                  ) tt ON t.ID = tt.ID
WHERE   t.ID IS NULL OR tt.ID IS NULL
```

Output:

```
ID  MissingValue
9   Missing in Table 2, 3
10  Missing in Table 1
```

Comment: Although a nice solution, it does not seem to return what is requested: "I want the query to return what is present in table1 and not find in table2 nor in table3. In addition, it should return what is present in table2 and table3 and not present in table1."

Comment: @Mackan, it does return that information :)
9 is `what is present in table1 and not find in table2 nor in table3;`
10 is `it should return what is present in table2 and table3 and not present in table1`

Comment: Aha, I guess we interpret the request differently :) I thought he would want 1-9 from table1, and also 10 since it's found in table3. Your solution makes more sense in any way (+1).

Answer (score 0):

> In addition, it should return what is present in table2 and table3 and not present in table1.

How do you want to differ between the two, when you return it all in one query?

To the original question, try this:

```
SELECT dr1.col1, dr1.col2
FROM table1 dr1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM table2 dr2
  WHERE dr2.col1 = dr1.col1
  AND dr2.col2 = dr1.col2)
AND NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM table3 dr3
  WHERE dr3.col1 = dr1.col1
  AND dr3.col2 = dr1.col2)
```

That way you get all data in table 1 that is not in table 2 or table 3.

Answer (score 0):

To find the records present in table1 and not present in table2 and table3, you could use the following query. I am assuming that there is a primary key field on both table2 and table3, which I refer to as `ID`. I have also eliminated the subselect.

```
SELECT dr1.col1, dr1.col2 from table1 dr1 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 dr2 
        ON dr1.col1 = dr2.col1 and dr1.col2 = dr2.col2 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN table3 dr3
        ON dr1.col1 = dr3.col1 and dr1.col2 = dr3.col2 and dr1.col3 = dr3.col3  
    WHERE dr2.ID is NULL AND dr3.ID is NULL
```

If you want to know what is present in table2 and table3 but not in table1, you cannot select from table1. Instead you could select from table2, joined to table3 and left outer join table 1:

```
SELECT dr2.col1, dr2.col2 from table2 dr2
    INNER JOIN  table3 dr3
        ON dr2.col1 = dr3.col1 and dr2.col2 = dr3.col2
    LEFT OUTER JOIN table1 dr1 
        ON dr1.col1 = dr2.col1 and dr1.col2 = dr2.col2 
    WHERE dr1.ID is NULL
```